# Visual Studio is caching old versions of assemblies during debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. I have had this problem since back in VS 2017, perhaps farther. The problem is that for certain projects (with no apparent rhyme or reason), VS seems to cache old versions of dependent assemblies. When I debug, if I've modified the code in those assemblies, I don't hit it / can't hit breakpoints. The solution is always to rebuild everything... TWICE... then launch.

What makes this hard to troubleshoot, IMHO, is that it's inconsistent, in that it doesn't happen with every project, but once it's a problem with a given project, it's always a problem for that project. Here's a little background about the structure of our solutions:

We create all of our mid-tier libraries in separate Solutions / Projects, and then build the debug versions of those. We deploy the dll / pdb files of those debug assemblies to a common BIN filder, which we then reference for any project that has dependencies. Our main application is a web application, with .net remoting. Our mid-tier services are exposed in "Remoting Server" application that implement the service layer and reference those mid-tier libraries I mentioned.

So, for example, the problem is that I'll make some change in some assembly. Let's call it corp.shopping.businessobjects. I build that, deploy it to the common bin, and it's referenced by the Corp.Shopping.RemotingServer project. If I make a change to a class in Corp.Shopping.BusinessObjects, deploy it and then debug the Remoting Server, my breakpoints don't work in that code and the new code changes aren't hit. It's like the thing is using some cached version of the assembly, even though looking at the dll / pdb files themselves in the output bin of the project, the common bin, and the output bin of the remoting server all show the correct date/time.

Obviously this makes unit testing an absolute NIGHTMARE when you cannot depend on the integrity of the code to debug it. Any suggestions on how to diagnose what's happening here? I have a feeling this is some sort of bug w/ Visual Studio, but I'm surprised it's been around this long if that's the case. I can't be the only one experiencing this sort of thing. Incidentally, it's not just "me"; it's any other developer as well. Again, once this is a problem for a particular project, it seems to be a problem with that project forever.

Comment: During debugging you can open Debug->Windows->Modules to check if the right dll is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, in our assembly files, we hard-code the version to 1.0.0.0. I think that's meant to keep us from ending up in DLL hell, but that's also (I'm guessing) going to make simply identifying the right assembly by version number more difficult, unless there's another build signature I can look for?